# Sort very long Linked List using Merge Sort or Quick Sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, quicksort, mergesort

I have to implement the famous LS command 
I am stuck because I end up with a very long Linked-List for each folder that I have to sort (ASCII, or time, or reverse order)

Here is my linked list structure,

```
 typedef struct     s_list
{
    void            *content;
    size_t          content_size;
    struct s_list   *next;
}                   t_list
```

Inside the `void *content` I put my Ls structure,

```
typedef struct      s_dir
{
    unsigned int    i;
    quad_t          blocks;
    char            *pathname;
    char            *name;
    ino_t           ino;
    uint8_t         type;
    uint16_t        mode;
    unsigned char   nlink;
    char            *usrname;
    char            *grpname;
    long long       size;
    time_t          time;
    struct s_dir    *rec;
    struct s_dir    *next;
    int             error;
}                   t_dir
```

I'm currently using this function to sort my list.

```
static void             sort_ascii(t_list **head)
{
    t_dir   *rep;
    t_list  *curr;
    void    *tmp;
    t_dir   *rep_next;

    curr = *head;
    while (curr && curr->next && (rep = (t_dir *)curr->content)
            && (rep_next = (t_dir *)curr->next->content))
    {
        if (ft_strcmp(rep->pathname, rep_next->pathname) > 0)
        {
            tmp = curr->content;
            curr->content = curr->next->content;
            curr->next->content = tmp;
            curr = *head;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

My problem is that this one is incredibly slow.

I would like to implement another sorting algorithm 
Merge sort or Quicksort, I don't know which one is best for my situation

I don't know at all how to implement those sorting method
and Its is completely new for me.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: i am gonna vote for mergesort

Comment: Take a look at [wiki psuedocode for bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) .

Comment: Thx for reply :) i think i will use mergesort but i need to learn how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sorting code is incorrect: you swap the `content` field but not the `content_size`. You are expected to sort the list elements by updating their `next` members and updating the `*head` argument.

Your method has quadratic complexity if not worse.  You should instead use mergesort that has a much lower time complexity of **O(N.log(N))**.

Here is an example (top down merge sort):

```
/* return the comparison status: 0 for equal, <0 if a < b, >0 if a>b */
int compare_ascii(t_list *a, t_list *b) {
    return ft_strcmp(((t_dir *)a->content)->pathname, ((t_dir *)b->content)->pathname);
}

t_list *merge(t_list *a, t_list *b, int (*cmp)(t_list *a, t_list *b)) {
    t_list *head = NULL;  /* head of the merged list */
    t_list **r = &head;   /* pointer to the node link */
    if (a && b) {
        for (;;) {
            if ((*cmp)(a, b) <= 0) {
                /* link the head node of list a */
                *r = a;
                r = &a->next;
                a = a->next;
                if (!a)
                    break;
            } else {
                /* link the head node of list b */
                *r = b;
                r = &b->next;
                b = b->next;
                if (!b)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    /* link the remaining part of a or b if any */
    *r = (a == NULL) ? b : a;
    return head;
}

t_list *mergesort(t_list *p, int (*cmp)(t_list *a, t_list *b)) {
    t_list *a, *b, *last = NULL;
    /* find the middle with 2 finger method: a moves twice as fast as b */
    for (a = b = p; a && a->next; a = a->next->next, b = b->next)
         last = b;
    if (last == NULL) {
        /* empty list or single element */
        return p;
    }
    /* split in the middle (before b) */
    last->next = NULL;
    /* sort each half and merge the sorted sublists */
    return merge(mergesort(p, cmp), mergesort(b, cmp), cmp);
}

void sort_ascii(t_list **head) {
    *head = mergesort(*head, compare_ascii);
}
```

As commented by **rcgldr**, bottom up merge sort is usually faster because it does not need to scan the lists to find the middle element, which may be expensive due to cache mismatches. The counterpart is it may perform more comparisons, but still with a time complexity of **O(N.log(N))** and is not recursive.

Here is a version of `mergesort` using bottom up merge sort:

```
t_list *mergesort(t_list *head, int (*cmp)(t_list *a, t_list *b)) {
    t_list *array[32]; // sorted sublists: array[i] has 2**i length if not null
    t_list *result = head;
    int i, top = 0;

    // merge nodes into array
    while (result != NULL) {
        t_list *next = result->next;
        result->next = NULL;
        // merge sorted sublists by increasing power of 2 sizes
        for (i = 0; i < top && array[i] != NULL; i++) {
            result = merge(array[i], result, cmp);
            array[i] = NULL;
        }
        // store the merged list, update top, do not go past end of array
        if (i == top) {
            if (top < 32)
                top++;
            else
                i--;
        }
        array[i] = result;
        result = next;
    }
    // merge all sorted sublists into single list
    result = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < top; i++) {
        result = merge(array[i], result, cmp);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Bottom up merge sort for linked lists is faster, since it doesn't involve any scanning to split sub-list, especially if the nodes are scattered in memory. You can look at the wiki example in my comment to the question.

Comment: Ho thank you a lot , i dont access the content_size later in my code so i havent noticed that i forgot to swap it too

Thank you , perfect answer , very easy to understand for me 

Works perfect